# Drawing fewer plots than specified in matplotlib subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 3, sharex='col', squeeze=False, figsize=(20, 10))
```

I want to plot 7 subplots and am using the command above. However it creates 9 plots (including 2 empty ones). How can I make sure that only 7 plots get drawn?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs  = plt.subplots(3,3)
fig.delaxes(axs[-1, -1])
fig.delaxes(axs[-1, -2])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @Serenity, what are the [-1, -1] and [-2, -2]?

Comment: You have a grid of 3x3 subplots. I set coordinates of subplots to remove (these are last two plots).